# Why is my div ordering reversed in this Bootstrap page?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Below I have added my HTML code. Currently, I can see First1 and First 2 in UI at the end, but my expected output First2 and First 1.

Current output:
[image]

Code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div ng-if="item" class="container-fluid" ng-class="item.loaderBorderClass">
    <div ng-if="!item.IsCollapsed" uib-collapse="item.isCollapsed">
        <div class="list-group">          
           <div class="row pull-right">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <strong>First 2</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row pull-right">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <strong>First 1</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure why it's looking like this in the UI.

I know if we swap the text, it will work as expected, but is there any reason it's coming like this because in code First 2 is coded first and the First 1 is coded second but in UI its showing differently in UI?

Comment: Swap the text?  or whats the question?

Comment: @Marc I know if we swap it will work as expected but is there any reason it's coming like this because in code First 2 is coded first and the First 1 is coded second

Comment: I would guess the same as Ekim gave you as answer. `pull-right` "override" the position from the "previous" element. Put both in a wrapping div, and align that.

Comment: You could also pull right the `.list-group` container and the order will be kept. But yes. Is because of the `pull-right` classes.

Answer (score 0):

I think it first of all prints " First 2" then put its to the right.
Then print "First 1" and put it to the right ( which is also the left of First2).

There are multiple ways to solve this.

1. You may change the order to solve it
2. Align both of them to the end without using "pull-right".

[Bootstrap Justify-Content d-flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content)

Do not forget that you should add d-flex in order to use justify-content

Here is an example ;

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-end">...</div>
```

Inside the `div` add your `col`

I hope this will solve.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).